# Why do I often get exceptions when uploading files using "multipart/form-data"?

Tags: java, struts2

I user enctype="multipart/form-data" in form to submit file.But in the case of no file to upload,Exceptions are often reported.

```
org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.multipart.JakartaMultiPartRequest.warn:68 - Unable to parse request
org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException: early EOF
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:362)
```

```
Caused by: org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException: early EOF
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInput.read(HttpInput.java:65)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.LimitedInputStream.read(LimitedInputStream.java:134)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.makeAvailable(MultipartStream.java:999)
```

I debugger the jar,find the Exception was thrown in MultipartStream.skipPreamble()

```
public boolean skipPreamble() throws IOException {
        // First delimiter may be not preceeded with a CRLF.
        System.arraycopy(boundary, 2, boundary, 0, boundary.length - 2);
        boundaryLength = boundary.length - 2;
        try {
            // Discard all data up to the delimiter.
            discardBodyData();

            // Read boundary - if succeeded, the stream contains an
            // encapsulation.
            return readBoundary();
        } catch (MalformedStreamException e) {
            return false;
        } finally {
            // Restore delimiter.
            System.arraycopy(boundary, 0, boundary, 2, boundary.length - 2);
            boundaryLength = boundary.length;
            boundary[0] = CR;
            boundary[1] = LF; //here!!!!this line will throw a IOException
        }
    }
```

I'm very confused, but I can't reproduce it steadily, because the problem is there and then it's not there. Has anyone encountered this problem?

Comment: I think you are debugging on a different source than what is actually running. Firstly, none of the provided stack-traces has an entry for `MutlipartInputStream.skipPreamble()`, contradicting your claim. Secondly, assigning a (probably) constant value to an array index just cannot throw an `IOException`.

Comment: "But in the case of no file to upload" - what do you mean here? Why would the upload even be submitted if nothing is uploaded?